# Create fan animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I need help with creating a fan animation. I'm creating a react app, but since stackoverflow doesn't support react snippet, I wrote the snippet in html.

I need the following:

1. When I click the `Turn on` button, it will start to slowly accelerate to some constant speed.
2. Continue rotating at a constant speed.
3. When the `Turn off` button is clicked, begin to slowly decrease speed and stop.

I am stuck with animating accelerating and decreasing speed and current animation is also laggy.

This is my attempt. Thank you for help.

```js
const turnOn = document.querySelector(".turn-on");
const turnOff = document.querySelector(".turn-off");

const rotor = document.querySelector(".rotor");

const rotatingClass = "rotating";

turnOn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (!rotor.classList.contains(rotatingClass)) {
        rotor.classList.add(rotatingClass);
    }
});

turnOff.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (rotor.classList.contains(rotatingClass)) {
        rotor.classList.remove(rotatingClass);
    }
});
```

```css
.rotor {
    animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.rotor.rotating {
    animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fan</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <svg width="512" height="512" viewBox="0 0 512 512" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g clip-path="url(#clip0_1_2)">
        <mask id="mask0_1_2" style="mask-type:alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="512" height="512">
        <path class="rotor" d="M506.679 204.398C505.262 197.512 502.307 192.599 496.887 188.122C453.569 152.322 393.494 154.729 316.661 195.34C311.647 190.326 306.22 186.088 300.137 182.438C353.091 134.931 401.362 114.986 444.946 122.601C457.796 124.846 466.695 110.122 458.733 99.7904C441.061 76.8547 420.948 58.181 396.768 42.2548C390.895 38.3877 385.333 37.0048 378.334 37.6699C322.39 42.9874 281.612 87.168 255.999 170.213C248.908 170.213 242.073 171.053 235.193 172.774C239.045 101.738 259.073 53.5023 295.278 28.0675C305.952 20.5691 301.832 3.86563 288.897 2.18738C260.182 -1.53431 232.757 -0.517742 204.397 5.32065C197.512 6.73789 192.598 9.69258 188.121 15.1131C152.322 58.4317 154.728 118.506 195.339 195.34C190.325 200.354 186.087 205.781 182.437 211.863C134.93 158.909 114.986 110.638 122.601 67.0542C124.846 54.204 110.122 45.3056 99.79 53.2664C76.8543 70.9384 58.1807 91.0511 42.2546 115.231C38.3875 121.104 37.0046 126.666 37.6697 133.666C42.9872 189.61 87.1676 230.388 170.212 256.001C170.212 263.093 171.052 269.927 172.773 276.807C101.737 272.955 53.502 252.927 28.0673 216.722C20.5691 206.048 3.86561 210.168 2.18737 223.103C-1.5343 251.818 -0.51774 279.243 5.32063 307.603C6.73786 314.489 9.69253 319.402 15.1131 323.879C58.4314 359.679 118.506 357.273 195.339 316.661C200.353 321.676 205.78 325.914 211.863 329.563C158.909 377.071 110.638 397.015 67.0539 389.4C54.2038 387.155 45.3054 401.879 53.2673 412.211C70.9393 435.146 91.0519 453.82 115.232 469.746C121.105 473.613 126.667 474.996 133.666 474.331C189.61 469.014 230.388 424.833 256.001 341.788C263.092 341.788 269.927 340.948 276.807 339.226C272.955 410.262 252.927 458.498 216.722 483.933C206.048 491.431 210.168 508.134 223.103 509.813C251.818 513.534 279.243 512.518 307.603 506.679C314.488 505.262 319.402 502.307 323.879 496.887C359.678 453.568 357.272 393.494 316.661 316.66C321.675 311.646 325.913 306.219 329.563 300.137C377.07 353.091 397.014 401.362 389.399 444.946C387.154 457.796 401.878 466.694 412.21 458.732C435.146 441.06 453.819 420.948 469.745 396.768C473.612 390.895 474.995 385.332 474.33 378.333C469.013 322.389 424.832 281.61 341.788 255.998C341.788 248.906 340.948 242.072 339.227 235.192C410.263 239.044 458.498 259.072 483.933 295.277C491.431 305.951 508.134 301.831 509.813 288.896C513.534 260.182 512.518 232.759 506.679 204.398ZM256.001 327.491C216.518 327.491 184.51 295.483 184.51 256.001C184.51 216.518 216.518 184.51 256.001 184.51C295.483 184.51 327.491 216.518 327.491 256.001C327.491 295.483 295.483 327.491 256.001 327.491Z" fill="black"/>
        </mask>
        <g mask="url(#mask0_1_2)">
        <rect width="512" height="512.002" fill="url(#paint0_linear_1_2)"/>
        </g>
        </g>
        <defs>
        <linearGradient id="paint0_linear_1_2" x1="256.683" y1="502.445" x2="512.001" y2="256.685" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop stop-color="#D9D9D9"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#9F9F9F"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <clipPath id="clip0_1_2">
        <rect width="512" height="512" fill="white"/>
        </clipPath>
        </defs>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="turn-on">Turn on</button>
        <button class="turn-off">Turn off</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For 1. & 2., you are probably best off with using two animations - one that runs only one time, for the "getting up to speed" part, and then when that one has finished (`animationend` event), you trigger an indefinitely running one with constant speed, that picks up at the same rotation angle the first one finished.

Comment: Getting it to slow down again from there smoothly, might be the a bit more complicated part. You would either have to get the current rotation value at the point when you want to start slowing it down, so that your next animation can smoothly pick up from there - or modify the endlessly running animation at that point, so that it will complete one more full rotation first and then end (if that is actually possible with an already running infinite animation, I never tried), so that you could trigger the slow down animation afterwards.

Comment: Looks difficult. Can it be simplified by applying transition on animation play state?

Comment: `animation-play-state` is either `running` or `paused`, how would you want to "transition" that?

Comment: I just thought he could make the transition between turning and not turning. Can you please provide me the code of your method? Or is there an example of a similar project?

Comment: I'm happy to give you some hints, but I will not write the whole thing for you.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you. I figured it out based on your tips. I still need to adjust the cubic bezier curve and duration, but I have the main part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out using framer motion libeary in React.

Install framer.

```
npm install framer-motion
```

```js
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const Fan = ({}) => {
    const [fanState, setFanState] = useState("none");

    // adjust these values to achieve smooth effect
    const constDuration = 2;
    const startDuration = 3;
    const stopDuration = 3;

    const bezierCurve = [0.42, 0, 1, 0.88];
    const bezierCurveInverse = [1 - bezierCurve[2], 1 - bezierCurve[3], 1 - bezierCurve[0], 1 - bezierCurve[1]];

    const startRotation = () => {
        setFanState("start");
        setTimeout(() => setFanState("const"), startDuration * 1000);
    };

    const stopRotation = () => {
        setFanState("stop");
    };

    const fanVariants = {
        start: { rotate: [0, 360], transition: { duration: startDuration, ease: bezierCurve } },
        const: { rotate: [0, 360], transition: { duration: constDuration, ease: "linear", repeat: Infinity } },
        stop: { rotate: 360, transition: { duration: stopDuration, ease: bezierCurveInverse } },
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <motion.img className="fan-container" animate={fanState} variants={fanVariants} src="your-fan-image-path" />
            <button onClick={startRotation}>Turn On</button>
            <button onClick={stopRotation}>Turn Off</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Add `transform-origin` to your CSS.

```css
.fan-container {
    transform-origin: 50% 50% !important;
}
```